# How to use XLOOKUP with an dynamic row count?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

At the result cell C2

```
=XLOOKUP(B2:B10, {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12})
```

The first column A is all text.
I want to convert to the month number.
Assuming the number of rows of the table might change (say to 100), then the lookup range B10 might need to be B100 instead of the initial B10. How to do it? Unless I specify a very large number just to be safe?

Comment: In A2 enter Date as mm/dd/yy or even dd/mm/yy and in B2 write this formula `=Text(A2,"MMMM")`,, U get moth's name as U are looking for.

Comment: **Cont,,** you may avoid XLOOKUP and just use `=Month(A2)`, you get Months as Number .

Comment: The problem is A2 is from the source data, Not from the value i key in. Unless you want me to change the format manually for every row of column A, which is not practical.

Comment: All depends that how you have entered DATEs in Col A. If are 05/02/2020 and then you applied TEXT format then no need to use any other then MONTH function. But if are literally written as Text (as we enter others like Name), Jun, 20 2020  then no formula will work. **And I'm sure that you have literally entered DATE as TEXT since used LEFT function (check screen shot)**!!

Comment: The actual file is a csv file I downloaded from website, containig all the historical prices of a stock. Sad to say, the date column, is really text only.

Comment: Then you need to convert them into DATE, otherwise,, the method U are using is to be used .

Answer (score 1):

I recommend converting your list to a formatted Table.

Put your cursor anywhere in the list of dates and press Ctrl+T. Your table should then look like this:

[image]

Now you can add formulas that refer to columns by name instead of by range and will automatically fill and adjust to every row that is added or removed:

[image]

Comment: This works if and when DATE written in any allowed format , dd/mm/yy or mm/dd/yy, and applied mmm dd, yy also TEXT, then only any formula will work otherwise get #VALUE error !!

Answer (score 0):

**For Excel 365**:

Here is one way using `FILTER()`:

```
=XLOOKUP(FILTER(B:B,LEN(B:B)), {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12})
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

If the data in column **B** was the result of a "spill-down" from **B2**, then you could use:

```
=XLOOKUP(B2#, {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12})
```

Comment: XLOOKUP is not a problem since OP has already used it,,, in fact in Col A has written DATEs literally as Text , check the attached screen shot has used LEFT to get moth name !!

Comment: the FILTER method, there is one issue, though, where the column title at B1 has to be removed. How to make FILTER method works without removing the column titles?

Comment: [link] (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiS2DCuBjCZK9Uoyxp2NrYQmLm0j?e=2ZHBqO) [link] As per the image above for column D which uses the `code`=XLOOKUP(B2#, {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"}, {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12})`code`  method, I do not undertstand why the SPILL happens.